# How to view Bytecode spring framework generated proxy classes?

Tags: spring, spring-aop, java-bytecode-asm, cglib

Is there API in Spring AOP/ASM libraries that lets us read the bytecode representation of Spring Generated Proxy class.
In my test code, I am having access to the class file.

```
private static void printClassBytes(String classFilePath) throws Exception{
    TraceClassVisitor visitor = new TraceClassVisitor(new PrintWriter(System.out));
    ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(new FileInputStream(new File("/xxx/asm_source/asmtest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/com/test/asm/Application.class")));
    
    reader.accept(visitor, 0);
}
```

But in my application, Proxy class is generated using Spring Integration Gateway in runtime, I only have object reference of Proxy Object. Is there some API in Spring or ASM that lets me find the bytecode of the corresponding Proxy class, using object reference
Something like

```
private static void printClassBytes(Object obj) throws Exception{
```

Comment: Your question is way too general. Please improve it by explaining in more detail what you want to do and show source code, so the community can see what you tried and what you struggle with. BTW, I had to download the Spring ASM module in order to find out what it is: just a re-packaged and relocated (different package names) variant of an older ASM version (class files from 2013). So maybe you should tag the question _asm_, too. I don't see any connection to _spring-aspects_ here.

Comment: I have proxy class. All examples I have use visitors on existing .class files. For the spring generated proxy is there some utility that help me print the bytecode

Comment: What was unclear about my request to edit the question and provide source code? Ideally, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce your problem would be nice. Please also explain what you need the byte code for. Your question seems to be an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898), asking about **how** to technically do something instead of explaining **what** your goal is, thereby closing the door to alternative (possibly better) solutions. There are ways to get the byte code of a class, but I like to understand why you think you need it.

Comment: I am asking because in order to write a class transformer and apply it via Java instrumentation, you do not need the byte code. Java instrumentation infrastructure will take care of feeding the byte code to your transformer. So really, I need to see your code in order to see more. Otherwise we are done here, I am afraid. P.S.: I just noticed you changed the whole question and its tags, no longer talking about ASM but CGLIB. What the heck?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I have a Spring Integration based application, which generates proxy objects in runtime. I am interested in getting hold of the bytecodes of those proxy objects to understand how Spring Integration Gateway works, under the hood. For now, I just want to print them for analyses purpose using TraceClassVisitor. I am new to the subject .... pardon me if I am again missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if Spring has on-board means to do that, but AFAIK the ASM classes embedded in Spring do not include the `TraceClassVisitor`. So if you like its output, you have to use ASM (artifact `asm-util`) directly, which I assume you did for your sample code. If you want to stick with on-board means, you can just write a transformer which dumps the full byte code as a class file into a file and then look at the file with the JDK command line tool `javap`, e.g. via `javap -c -p -v MyDumpedBytes.class`.

Anyway, an easy thing to do is to implement a Java agent and attach it to the Java command line starting the Spring project via `-javaagent:/path/to/my-agent.jar`. I found [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instrumentation) for you which explains how to implement a simple Java agent with manifest file etc. and also how to attach it to a running process via Java attach API. The article uses Javassist as an example for writing a transformer, but you can just use ASM instead.

Your Java agent + transformer would look something like this:

```java
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

class TraceClassTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

  /**
   * Attach agent dynamically after JVM start-up
   */
  public static void agentmain(String commandLineOptions, Instrumentation instr) {
    premain(commandLineOptions, instr);
  }

  /**
   * Start agent via <code>-javaagent:/path/to/my-agent.jar=<i>options</i></code> JVM parameter
   */
  public static void premain(String commandLineOptions, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    TraceClassTransformer transformer = new TraceClassTransformer();
    instrumentation.addTransformer(transformer, true);
  }

  @Override
  public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    dumpClass(classfileBuffer);
    // Do not apply any transformation
    return null;
  }

  private void dumpClass(byte[] classfileBuffer) {
    TraceClassVisitor visitor = new TraceClassVisitor(new PrintWriter(System.out));
    ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
    reader.accept(visitor, 0);
  }

}
```

Just make sure that the agent's manifest enables retransformation via `Can-Retransform-Classes: true`.

After the agent has started, you can just call `instrumentation.retransformClasses(proxyInstance.getClass());` and then enjoy the log output.

In order to make it a bit simpler for this example, let us use [`byte-buddy-agent`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.10.13) which contains a neat little tool set to attach transformers during runtime without the need to wrap them into Java agents. The artifact is small and does not contain the rest of ByteBuddy, just the agent tool.

That would simplify your class to (you can keep or drop the `premain` and `agentmain` methods, depending on whether you are planning to use the class as a Java agent or not):

```java
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

class TraceClassTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnmodifiableClassException {
    // Easy way to get an Instrumentation instance, so we can directly register our transformer on it
    Instrumentation instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
    // I am just creating a Java dynamic proxy for a JRE interface. In your own application,
    // you would just get a reference to a dynamic proxy created by Spring.
    Object proxyInstance = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
      Closeable.class.getClassLoader(),
      new Class<?>[] { Closeable.class },
      (proxy, method, args1) -> null
    );

    // Register + use dummy ClassFileTransformer, then unregister again (optional)
    TraceClassTransformer transformer = new TraceClassTransformer();
    try {
      instrumentation.addTransformer(transformer, true);
      instrumentation.retransformClasses(proxyInstance.getClass());
    }
    finally {
      instrumentation.removeTransformer(transformer);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    dumpClass(classfileBuffer);
    // Do not apply any transformation
    return null;
  }

  private void dumpClass(byte[] classfileBuffer) {
    TraceClassVisitor visitor = new TraceClassVisitor(new PrintWriter(System.out));
    ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
    reader.accept(visitor, 0);
  }
}
```

When running the sample `main` class, you get a console log like:

```
// class version 58.0 (58)
// access flags 0x11
public final class com/sun/proxy/$Proxy0 extends java/lang/reflect/Proxy implements java/io/Closeable {


  // access flags 0xA
  private static Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; m0

  // access flags 0xA
  private static Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; m1

  // access flags 0xA
  private static Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; m2

  // access flags 0xA
  private static Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; m3

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>(Ljava/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler;)V
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/reflect/Proxy.<init> (Ljava/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler;)V
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2

(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!!!! I really appreciate your help :)